# What to do about my locked answer to a post?

Tags: support, locked-posts

A post of mine has been locked. There was an error in the answer I gave, which was pointed out, and I wanted to correct it, but it got locked.

How do I unlock it so I can fix it?

What is the purpose of the lock?

Comment: Only moderator can unlock a post.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot unlock a post. The very point of locking a post is to prevent users (including the owner) from altering it.

See [What is a "locked" post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) for further details.

You can contact a moderator via a flag or ask in the [Math mods' office chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office) to get further details and to inquire under what conditions the post could be unlocked.

For the specific case, for some reason you altered the post, like, ten times. This creates noise. You now have some time to decide what you actually want to do. Once you figured that out, contact one of us, as indicated above.

Comment: When I was altering the post, I was simply trying to restore what I had written without all the editing which someone else had done, without my knowledge or permission.  How do I contact "one of us"?

Comment: [Nobody else edited it](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2883812/revisions), @herbsteinberg.

Comment: Can you forget all the roll backs?  The text needs one minor correction.  Let me get on with it!

Comment: I'll unlock the post. I explained in the post how you can contact us "flag, other" or joint the chat room I mentioned.